# what are reasons for showing PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DB_Error as array while running a php script?

Tags: php

what are reasons for showing:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DB_Error as array

while running a php script?

I received this error on a line while running a php page and I want to know the situations that could produce the above error condition?

Comment: Without seeing your code it is very tuf to rectify the error but again re-validate your database include file path

Answer (score 0):

Your DB query function seems to return an array if the query succeeded and return an object `DB_Error` if something failed with the query..

It seems that there is an error with your query. Try something like this:

```
$result = $db->query(...);

// error handler
if(is_a($result, 'DB_Error')) {
    var_dump($result);
    die('error!');
}

// regular code to fetch records. Will trigger the error
// if $result is not an array.
foreach($result as $record) {

}
```